# cmake unknown linkage, who asked for linking?

Tags: cmake

I've an cmake project using different toolchains. (`native x86`, `a yocto generated`, and a `precompiled`) The project includes some libraries, they are all fine and linked correctly.

```
find_package(Boost 
                1.74.0
                REQUIRED 
                COMPONENTS log log_setup system filesystem thread program_options )

find_library(LIB_MOSQPP mosquittopp REQUIRED)
find_library(LIB_MOSQ mosquitto REQUIRED)
find_library(LIB_PTHREAD pthread REQUIRED)
find_library(LIB_CRYPTO crypto REQUIRED)
find_library(LIB_SSL ssl REQUIRED)
```

Now, with the precompiled toolchain cmake links to libicu `-licudata -licui18n -licuuc` with the others not. Is there a way to find out why libicu is linked? Resp. who/which module is depending on on it?

The linker command looks like follow:

```sh
cat ./CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/link.txt:1

/home/shell/tmp/armv7-eabihf--musl--stable-2020.08-1/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-musleabihf-g++ --sysroot=/home/shell/tmp/armv7-eabihf--musl--stable-2020.08-1/arm-buildroot-linux-musleabihf/sysroot/  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/src/AccumulatedData.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/src/AgentConfig.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/src/BasicDataSet.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/src/OBCAgent.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/LFMMsgParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/MsgPacker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/MsgParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/MsgSplitter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/ObcConfig.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/PlayMqtt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/OBCAgent.dir/home/shell/sh-services/src/Common/src/boost_helper.cpp.o -o OBCAgent   -L/home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_log_setup.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libpthread.a /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libmosquittopp.so /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libmosquitto.so /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libcares.so /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libssl.so /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libcrypto.so /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.75.0 -lrt /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.75.0 /home/shell/tmp/alpine/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.75.0 -licudata -licui18n -licuuc
```

Comment: Examine exact linker's **command line** and locate a position of the "unknown" linkage in it. Then look on the **nearest linkage arguments**: There is a high chance that in the `CMakeLists.txt` the "unknown linkage" is added **immediately** before/after the nearest linkages... or as a part of that nearest linkages. E.g. If you find in the command line an argument `-licuil8n` near the `-lboost_xxx` one, then it could be that `icudata` is linked near the Boost libraries, or it is a part of Boost library `Boost:xxx`.

Comment: ok, thanks @Tsyvarev. I added the linker command in the question. So it looks like `libboost_regex` does it?

Comment: @sturzenegger: [Boost.Regex uses ICU for its Unicode support](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/intro.html), yes. It is compiled in (or not) at build time, so it is possible to have Boost.Regex without that dependency (and without Unicode support, obviously). Boost.Locale is another Boost library that requires ICU.

Comment: @DevSolar, ah I use different rootfs too. So different libboost package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware about CMake support about such feature - "give me the origin of some linkage" - but taking into account the CMake workflow, the following way could help in such task.

1. Obtain an **exact string** with linker arguments, which includes "unknown" linkage.

   E.g. with Makefile generator you could run `make VERBOSE=1` which will print exact command lines executed. Also, in some cases CMake creates `link.txt` files with the linker's arguments.
2. **Locate** in the string with the linker's argument the "unknown" linkage which you are interested in.
3. Note to the **nearest linkage arguments**, which origin you are able to identify. Exactly these arguments could give you a hint about the "unknown" linkage:

   - It is possible that origin of the "unknown" linkage is **near** the one of the nearest linkage argument (in the same order!).
   - It is possible that "unknown" linkage is requested in the **same** `target_link_libraries` call as the nearest linkage argument.
   - Finally, it is possible that "unknown" linkage and the nearest one are part of the same IMPORTED/INTERFACE library **target**.

     E.g. `find_package(XXX)` could create IMPORTED/INTERFACE targets in form of `XXX::yyy`, which incorporate both the libraries belonging to the package itself and the libraries they depend upon.